# Unable to insert data in Postgres using Jdbc

Tags: postgresql, pyspark, jdbc, aws-databricks

I am attempting to insert data into a PostgreSQL database using PySpark with JDBC. However, during the data insertion process, it is unexpectedly attempting to recreate the table and producing the following output.

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: relation "account" already exists
```

I am trying to use the below code snippet to write the data in Postgres.

```
def postgres_writes(url, driver, username, password, table_name, df):
df.write \
  .format("jdbc") \
  .option("url", url) \
  .option("dbtable", table_name) \
  .option("user", username) \
  .option("password", password) \
  .option("driver", driver) \
  .mode("append") \
  .save()
```

I want to append the data in an existing table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please make sure that, you are passing appropriate jdbc url. As per Postgres documentation [Documentation Link](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/use/) you can use below JDBC URL's forms

```
jdbc:postgresql:database
jdbc:postgresql:/
jdbc:postgresql://host/database
jdbc:postgresql://host/
jdbc:postgresql://host:port/database
jdbc:postgresql://host:port/
```

Also try to recreate the table and try to load the data again. There might be some issue at Spark session level.

Comment: I am using jdbc:postgresql://host:port/database format

Comment: Ok. I tried your scenario. I am able to append the data.

Comment: Is there any configuration I need to change in the DB side?

Comment: Deleting and recreating the table resolve the issue